# Мультиплатформенный запуск executable файла из C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Предположим, есть программа, которая должна в зависимости от системы Linux/Windows запускать исполняемый файл. 
Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке решение данной проблемы, кроме как путем использование `system()` ? 
Или если нет функции, подходящей под обе ОС, есть ли способ сделать вызов .exe файла не используя system/winapi, что-то на подобии Process.Start в c#?

p.s. 

если решения нет в стандартной библиотеке, буду очень признателен и другим ответам

Comment: используфте  boost.process

Comment: Можно подумать что `Process.Start в c#` использует что-то иное от winapi. А по сути, как вы себе это представляете? Бинарник собран под какую плятформу? который должен что-то там запускать? или имеется в виду работа на другой ОС из под эмулятора?

Comment: @NewView, касательно ```Process.Start```, наверное, да. Я не сильно представляю себе это в данный момент, поэтому и был задан вопрос, чтобы узнать есть ли какой-то способ. х86-64.

Comment: При чем тут архитектура `х86-64`? Под линукс формат исполняемого файла совершенной иной, там `ELF`. Другими словами, ваша программа должна быть собрана отдельно под каждую платформу, если она внутри совместима по вызовам и собереться.. соответственно чего запускать можно смело определять в блоках `#if defined(__linux)`

Comment: @NewView, спасибо, я понимаю. Она и будет собираться под каждую платформу: отдельно под win и отдельно под linux, следовательно у меня будет два разных executable, и каждый будет вызываться в зависимости от дефайна, да. Но вопрос был немного в другом. В любом случае, спасибо за Ваш комментарий, хорошего дня/вечера :)

Comment: на линукс PE файлы можно запускать в wine (с грехом пополам), на windows ELF файлы можно запускать нативно в линуксовой подсистеме

Comment: @VTT, ну, мной предполагалось, что просто код будет перекомпилирован и слинкован на каждой платформе отдельно, поэтому с этим пока вопроса не возникало, но учту, спасибо Вам!

Comment: В таком случае есть же совместимые с linux функции `exec*` https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl , вот их и используйте, под win тогда собирать `mingw`. Совместимость в поведении по практике не 100%, сказывается отсутствие `fork()` на вин платформе..

Comment: Посмотрите на [posix_spawn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html) для \*nix и семейство [_spawn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=vs-2019) в винде. Возможно с минимальными надстройками интерфейса это как раз то, о чем вы спрашиваете.